# How to extract only English words from a from big text corpus using nltk?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp

I am want remove all  non dictionary english words from text corpus. I have removed stopwords, tokenized and countvectorized the data. I need extract only the English words and attach them back to the dataframe .

```
data['Clean_addr'] = data['Adj_Addr'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split()]))
        data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item.lower() for item in x if  not  item.isdigit()]))
        data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item.lower() for item in x if item not in string.punctuation]))
        data['Clean_addr'] = data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split() if item not in (new_stop_words)]))
        cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 200,analyzer='word')
        cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))
```

Sample Dump of the File I am using

https://www.dropbox.com/s/allhfdxni0kfyn6/Test.csv?dl=0

Comment: How do you define English? Should proper names like Zaaba and Robeco be removed? How large an English dictionary do you need (OED has a few hundred thousand words, the English Wikipedia a couple million unique tokens, some of which are arguably not English)?

Comment: @tripleee I want remove  proper names and chinese names

Comment: @pankaj, in order for your algorithm to recognize whether a word is Chinese or English, you need to define a database with English/Chinese words which your algorithm can make the comparison between the words it finds and the words in database. Note that your algorithm isn't capable of figuring those stuff on its own without defining it what is a Chinese word and what is an English word.

Comment: @Flika205, we can you english word corpus inside NLTK

Answer (score 2):

after you first tokenize your text corpus, you could instead **stem** the word tokens

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language="english")
```

[`SnowballStemmer`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer)

- is algorithm executing [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)

  - stemming is just the process of breaking a word down into its root.
- is passed the [argument 'english'](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html)   ↦   [**porter2** stemming](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html) algorithm

  - more precisely, this 'english' argument    ↦   [`stem.snowball.EnglishStemmer`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.snowball.EnglishStemmer)
  - (*porter2* stemmer considered to be [better than](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-popular-stemming-algorithms-in-Text-Classification) the original `porter` stemmer)

```
stems = [stemmer.stem(t) for t in tokenized]
```

Above, I define a list comprehension, which executes as follows:

1. list comprehension loops over our tokenized input `list` *tokenized*

   - (*tokenized* can also be any other other iterable input instance)
2. list comprehension's action is to perform a `.stem` method on each tokenized word using the `SnowballStemmer` instance *stemmer*
3. list comprehension then collects **only** the set of English stems

   - i.e., it is a list that should collect *only* stemmed English word tokens

> Caveat:   list comprehension could conceivably include certain *identical* inflected words in other languages which English decendends from because *porter2*  would mistakenly think them English words

Comment: stemming would break the  english words to root words.In my case I want to keep only the english words as such and not to break to into root words. Example  Xan higher secondary  school should be outputed as higher secondary  school

Comment: You could just nest the list comprehension’s action in this case. i.e., loop over the tokenized words and Boolean- check if the stemmer instance actually returned something, and then add the corresponding original word to some list/container.

Will try to code this up when I get a chance.

Comment: ,I tried that but didnt work, If it worked for you. can you update the code.

Comment: I tried the suggested code, but non-English words do not get away, their stems are exactly the initial words themselves @user188466

Answer (score 0):

## Down To The Essence

I had a VERY similar need. Your question appeared in my search. Felt I needed to look further, and I found [THIS](https://intellipaat.com/community/5638/removing-non-english-words-from-text-using-python). I did a bit of modification for my specific needs (only English words from TONS of technical data sheets = no numbers or test standards or values or units, etc.). After much pain with other approaches, the below worked. I hope it can be a good launching point for you and others.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')


file_name = 'Full path to your file'
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.replace('\n', ' ')

new_text = " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text)
                    if w.lower() in words
                    and w.lower() not in stop_words
                    and len(w.lower()) > 1)

print(new_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the pyenchant library to do this.

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
def get_eng_words(data):
    eng =[]

    for sample in tqdm(data):
        sentence=''
        word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sample)
            for word in word_tokens:
            if(d.check(word)):
                if(sentence ==''):
                    sentence = sentence + word
                else:
                    sentence = sentence +" "+ word
        print(sentence)
        eng.append(sentence)
    return eng
```

To save it just do this!

```
sentences=get_eng_words(df['column'])
df['column']=pd.DataFrame(sentences)
```

Hope it helps anyone!